# Showing that the following reasoning is wrong

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose we have a function of two variables $f(x,y)$. We know that the function is jointly convex in the feasible set. Furthermore, the feasible set is convex. So the problem of minimizing $f(x,y)$ over the feasible set is a convex optimization problem. Assuming that the constraints are non-active. In this case if we take the derivative of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ and put it equal to zero to get an equation of the form $y=g(x)$. After that we replace $y$ by $g(x)$ in the original objective function $f(x,y)$ (i.e. we write $f(x,g(x))$) and then minimize $f(x,g(x))$ with respect to $x$. What is the way to show that this reasoning is wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Is the first derivative (in "of $f(x,y)$ with respect to") with $y$? Why do you think this reasoning is wrong?

Comment: @gerw no its with respect to $x$

Comment: Why should this reasoning be wrong? I could imagine that it works if you can really obtain such a function $g$. Maybe you should try some simple examples (i.e. quadratic functions).

Comment: @gerw ok then I assume this reasoning is right then.

Comment: @gerw the first derivative is with respect to $x$

Comment: Setting ${\partial f(x,y) \over \partial x} = 0$ may result in some set of minimisers $\{  (x,y) \}$, and this is not necessarily expressible as the graph of a function of $x$. Even if it is, you have performed the minimisation over $x$, not $y$, so you should be replacing $x$, not $y$.

Comment: @copper.hat but if we replace $y$ then what will be the result? will it be local minimum? or some stationary point? or just nothing at all?

Comment: @FrankMoses: I have no idea what it would mean. If you use the partial with respect to $x$, then $y$ is an innocent bystander...